# Review process of revised journal paper

Tags: peer-review

A few months ago, I was asked to review a paper. The result of the review process was a "Revise".

So now I was asked again to read the revised version of the paper. But now I can only select "Accept Review" or "Decline Review".

Does this mean that the paper will be reviewed again with other reviewers?

Comment: Ask the editor you are doing the review for - they will know exactly how their process works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means they're inviting you to review the revision. If you accept the review, then you get to read the paper, make new comments, make new recommendation, etc. If you decline, they'll either find someone else or make a decision.

Based on your description, there isn't enough information to tell if there are other reviewers invited. You certainly are, but don't know about the others.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.